# PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error?

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax-error

i get this error when using my php code

PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in your code on line 7

please help me i dont understand what ive done wrong here
php code :

```
<?php


if ( $ready == "false" ) { 
$rand =  chr(rand(97, 122)). chr(rand(97, 122)). chr(rand(97, 122)); 
$folder = "uploads/".$rand 
}

if ( !is_dir($folder) ) {
    $ready = "true"
}
if ( is_dir($folder) ) {
    $ready = "false"
}

if ( $ready == "true" ) {
$that = "yes"
mkdir("uploads/".$rand);
$to = "Uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $to);
echo "uploaded";
}
?>


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Choose a file:</label>
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="upload" onclick="$other = "yes""/>

</form>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error and is unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: If you have a question like this, look at line 7, or the proceeding line, to see what is wrong with the code. If you install an IDE (like Netbeans or Eclipse) it will show you what is wrong with it, without you having to run the code.

Comment: Please take a look at your code. It misses `;` in several places.

Comment: damn man, you missed so many `;` I thought this was VB

Comment: For one thing, `$folder = "uploads/".$rand` should read as `$folder = "uploads/".$rand;`. Missing ending `;`. Plus you have no `action=` set for your form, unless you're using Ajax.

Comment: **PLUS**: `mkdir("uploads/".$rand); $to = "Uploads/"` (`uploads` != `Uploads`). **!=** << does NOT equal ;-) **Major FAIL**.

Comment: I suggest you consult the PHP manual on uploading files, and search for *php upload script* on the Internet. **PHP link** >>> http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have miss `;` in many lines complete code:

```
if ( $ready == "false" ) { 
  $rand =  chr(rand(97, 122)). chr(rand(97, 122)). chr(rand(97, 122)); 
  $folder = "uploads/".$rand ;
}

if ( !is_dir($folder) ) {
    $ready = "true";
}
if ( is_dir($folder) ) {
    $ready = "false";
}

if ( $ready == "true" ) {
  $that = "yes";
  mkdir("uploads/".$rand);
  $to = "uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $to);
  echo "uploaded";
}
```

Comment: Missed ; is several places.

Comment: `mkdir("uploads/".$rand); $to = "Uploads/"` (`uploads` != `Uploads`). **!=** << does NOT equal ;-) **Major FAIL**, depending if you're on Linux or Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I haven't see it! @Fred

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri You're quite welcome.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot a semicolon at the end of line 7.  The statement is not complete, so the parser does not expect the curly bracket.

```
if ( $ready == "false" ) { 
    $rand =  chr(rand(97, 122)). chr(rand(97, 122)). chr(rand(97, 122)); 
    $folder = "uploads/".$rand ;
}
```

Comment: now you should know what that error message means.  You're going to see it again a few times after you make this correction, so now you know how to fix it.

Comment: Amongst many other bad syntax. The OP's code is literally **S=T=I=T=C=H=E=D** with errors.

Comment: OP should check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_refinement

Comment: Exactly, as well as the link to PHP manual on the subject that I posted under his original post.